# A non-smooth map with smooth Jacobian?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, jacobian

I am looking for an example of a non-smooth Sobolev map $f \in W_{\text{loc}}^{1,d}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^d)$, where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, such that $\det df \in C^{\infty}$ is everywhere non-zero.

In other words, I am looking for a map which is less regular that its Jacobian.

Comment: $df$ in the usual sense or in the distributions sense?

Comment: I meant $df$ in the usual sense. Is there any difference between this interpretation and the distributional interpretation?

Comment: In the distributional sense, $f = g$ a.e. for some differentiable $g$ is enough. In this case $f$ can be discontinuous in every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, a shear deformation $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ 
$$
f(x, y) = (x, y + h(x))
$$
where $h$ is a Sobolev function. The Jacobian determinant is identically $1$.